# Using .isalnum() in a try statement

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to get isalnum() working within a try statement. I will result in a False but will not execute the except statement. Why?

Tried a few things, one thing works is having a line that checks isalnum() outside the try statement. Then checking is that statement is True or Fasle. 
This seems a round about way of doing it and I feel there should be a better was of checking withing a try statement.

E.g

```
while True
    string = input()
    try:
        check = string.isalnum()
        break

    except ValueError:
        print("{} must be a number or a letter.".format(string))
        continue
```

Comment: `False` returned does not imply that that's an exception. It's a success operation in a negative scenario.

Comment: @Austin thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try and Except**
>
> If an error is encountered, a try block code execution is stopped and
> transferred down to the except block.

.

> **The isalnum() method**
>
> returns True if all characters in the string are alphanumeric (either alphabets or numbers). If not, it returns
> False.

NOTE:

in your case it makes no sense to use it. you will never have an error because you will have True or False from isalnum(), the except statement will never execute in your case

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing an exception being thrown with a `False` being returned.

The try except code you setup will try to call `string.isalnum()` AND if that breaks in such a way that it give s a `ValueError` your except part will run.  The problem is, `string.isalnum()` doesn't throw `ValueError`, it will return either `True` if your string is alphanumeric, `False` otherwise.  You can check this using 1 line scripts:

```
"gfdgksjhfgyuierg634786234693".isalnum()

>>> True

"()**^&*%$%$#%#@%$@^%%(^&%(^".isalnum()

>>> False
```

If either of these raised an exception you would see it instead of the `True` / `False`